# “HHeelllloo,, EEaarrtthh!!”

Tags: code-golf, string, kolmogorov-complexity, source-layout, hello-world

Much like [this challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world), write a program or function that takes no input and prints or returns the string

```
Hello, Earth!
```

with an optional trailing newline.

The catch is that your program must be an even number of characters long, and each two character chunk of your program must consist of identical characters.

For example, a valid program might look like

```
AAbb==11++♥♥

[[--  2222]]
```

because every two character chunk (`AA`, `bb`, `==`, `11`, etc.) is made of two identical characters (even the newlines).

A program such as

```
AAbB==11++♥♥

[[--  2222]]
```

would not be valid because the `bB` chunk is not made of identical characters.

The only exception to the rule is that `\r\n` should be treated a single, generic "newline" character since replacing it with `\r\r\n\n` wouldn't work or make sense for some languages and systems.

**The shortest code in bytes wins**. The example is 30 bytes long (not 15, not 13).

Comment: You are banning most non esolangs

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala That's the way it goes.

Comment: -1 for trivial challenge masked by source-layout/restricted-source (something new users are heavily bashed for). Also I dislike the narrow language restrictions

Comment: @Downgoat I think this a perfectly valid/interesting challenge, and I don't see any language restrictions.

Comment: @ConorO'Brien you may vote how you like. I am entitled as so too, I always comment when I downvote

Comment: @Downgoat s/downvote/downgoat most non esolang like languages are arbitrarily disqualified like this. I support the downgoat. +1 to your comments

Comment: @RohanJhunjhunwala To be clear, no languages have been disqualified, it just may be impossible in many. And I think it's good once in a while to have a challenge that lets real esolangs shine. Most challenges are invariably full of mainstream and golfing language answers as there is no need for anything more exceptional.

Comment: @HelkaHomba I understand that no language has been explicitly banned, but I feel most good challenges should at least remain theoretically possible in most Turing Complete challenges. It is nothing personal.

Comment: "Hello, Earth!" has an odd number of characters. That'll make it harder...

Comment: Not trying to start/prolong a discussion, and you're certainly entitled to vote as you see fit, but new users usually create yet another incarnation of *perform task T without using the characters XYZ or the built-in B*, which is utterly repetitive and on occasions unclear.

Comment: @Sp3000: It´s not an exact duplicate. The other challenge has the subsequent restriction only on certain positions.

Comment: @Titus I think you may have misread the other specification. The wording is a bit more convoluted than in this challenge, but it's also saying that every pair of characters needs to be identical.

Comment: @MartinEnder: Oh right. I misread 2n as 2^n.

Answer (score 6):

## [Lenguage](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Lenguage), 1354616599400377002855073561913010716386821416114463012 bytes

It's [1354616599400377002855073561913010716386821416114463012](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binary+to+decimal+00111000100100100100100100101000001111101000110000111000101000000000000000001111101000000010000000000000000000000010010000000000010011000101000000000000000001111101000010000100100100) zeroes:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...00000000
```

---

It's this BF program:

```
-[------->+<]>-.-[->+++++<]>++.+++++++..+++.[->+++++<]>+.------------.++[->++<]>+.+[------>+<]>.--[--->+<]>---.++.------------.--[--->+<]>-.
```

Converted into binary:

```
001110001001001001001001001010000011111010001100001110001010000000000000000011111010000000100000000000000000000000100100000000000100110001010000000000000000011111010000100001001001001001001001001001001001001100000000110001010000000011111010000100000110001001001001001001010000011111010100001001110001001001010000011111010001001001100000000100001001001001001001001001001001001001100001001110001001001010000011111010001100
```

Converted into a decimal number:

```
1354616599400377002855073561913010716386821416114463012
```

With that many zeroes. Hooray for lenguage!

Comment: I had a 70 byte fish answer but didn't finish before this was closed...

Comment: @Blue Do you mean the shell?

Comment: @EriktheGolfer it was pretty much the same as the fish answer of the duped questions, just like this is kind of like the unary answer of the duped question.

Comment: @Blue I mean, is it ><> or is it `fish`? I guess it's ><>, but that's not called 'Fish', it's the Esolang page that has technical limitations.